# Javascript - List (array) length and getting an item from the list not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, quokka.js

I'm practicing JavaScript (just started this week) on vscode with the Quokka.js extension. Right now I'm initializing a list called "things" and trying to get the length of the list and getting some items out of it. This is my code:

```
var things = ['bananas', 'apples', 7];
things.length;
things[0];
```

The last two rows return nothing to me, not even "undefined". 
**How do I get vscode to return the length and the first object from the list using [0]? If it is not possible in vscode, what program should I use for learning JavaScript?**

I also tried initializing the list as an array with

```
Array things = ['bananas', 'apples', 7];
```

but this does not seem to be allowed.
Moreover, for example the command

```
things.splice
```

seems to work in vscode.

Comment: Are you running your code in a browser? And how to you want to visualize the content? Do you want to show it on the webpage or do you want to debug it using something like `console.log` or `alert`?

Comment: @EvertvdH. I'm just at the beginning of a very beginner JS course. I actually don't know how I should visualize the content. Do you have any recommendations? A browser (Chrome) was at least used in some of the video lessons.

Comment: For now I would just follow whatever the course is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're using Quokka, it's better to output using `console.log`. Quokka works very well with `console.log`.

Also try not to use `var` or declare array using `Array`. This is JavaScript, not Java.

```js
// Do not use var
let things = ['bananas', 'apples', 7];
console.log(things.length);
console.log(things[0]);
```

```js
// This will not work
// This does not make any sense either
Array things = ['bananas', 'apples', 7];
```

JavaScript Array is not Class or an interface by using which you can declare it's instances. JavaScript Array is a global object. **There are no classes in JavaScript**.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for!